# Import Plot.ly React Component into Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, plotly, meteor-react

While [following the instructions](https://github.com/benjeffery/react-plotlyjs) to use the React component of Plotly in Meteor,

```
import createPlotlyComponent from 'react-plotlyjs';
import Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly-cartesian';
const PlotlyComponent = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);
```

gives the error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'plotly.js/dist/plotly-cartesian'
```

How do we install/load `plotly-cartesian`? `react-plotlyjs` NPM package has already been installed.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "chart-test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",
    "pondjs": "^0.8.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-plotlyjs": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: @pmirnd Updated with `package.json`

Comment: @Nyxynyx, did you come up with a solution? I am in the same situation

Comment: @user3314548 No, still looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the

```
 "plotly.js": "^1.26.1",
```

Workaround for plotly that works for me is to import `'plotly.js/dist/plotly'` instead of the cartesian version.

This issue may align with this suggesstion: https://github.com/benjeffery/react-plotlyjs/issues/15